# Use a parameter in an add_action function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an array that I want to pass to a function that I'm calling with `add_action`. Here is the code I have.

```
$packagesArray = array(3453, 3489, 6900, 5432);

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_upgrades', 20, 1);
do_action('check_upgrades', $packagesArray);

function check_upgrades($param){

    print_r($param);

}
```

Why does this not print out the 4 items in the array?

Comment: What does it print out? Does the check_upgrades function get called at all?

Comment: You seem to be trying to call a function as an action? `do_action('check_upgrades', $packagesArray);` will call the action `check_upgrades`, not the function that is similarly named. You could call `woocommerce_before_cart` to get that action invoked, but generally speaking you shouldn't call someone else's actions unless they explicitly document that you can. Is there s reason that you cannot just call the function `check_upgrades`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
$packagesArray = array(3453, 3489, 6900, 5432);

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_upgrades', 20, 1);
do_action_ref_array('woocommerce_before_cart', $packagesArray);

function check_upgrades($param){

    print_r($param);
```

See in the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action_ref_array/